# AUCTeX does not compile if the local variable is already set

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm basically want to ask the question that was asked in [Tex Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) but was considered off-topic there (this is the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311306/auctex-not-compiling-on-c-c-c-c-tex-master-file-ask-master-file-already-set) to the question).

When I am trying to compile (using the command `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-a`) 
 a latex document **which already has the needed local variables** to point to the `master-file` like lines below at the end:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

or if the `master-file` is another file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "fileNameOfMasterFile"
%%% End:
```

it does not compile and instead, just shows the following message`Master file already set` in the mini buffer.

If I simply delete the local variable `%%% TeX-master: "fileNameOfMasterFile"` or `%%% TeX-master: t` and try to compile again (using the command `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-a`) it asks for the `master-file` and compiles as usual. Further on, it works normally when I compile again. But if I simply close the buffer and (re-)open the file again I face the same issue.

Is it a natural behavior? If not, any idea why this happens and how I can solve it?

If needed, I have the following in my `init` file:

```
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

**Add-on:** I'm suspicious that this might be related to AUCTeX version. What I just explained in the question was tested on AUCTeXversion 12.2.0 and I tried with a similar setting (same init file but an older emacs) with an older version AUCTeX (12.1.2)(on a different machine) and it works as it is expected.

Comment: Do you also have `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in your init file?

Comment: also tried that one. The same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

Change to `(setq-default TeX-master t)` and don't forget to omit the "tex" extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but didn't work :( It causes a different problem it didn't recognize the master file and compile it as it's a file on its own (error like missing \begin{doc... ). If delete the local variable line (similar to what I explained aboce), then it works.

Comment: I'm suspicious that this is related to AUCTeX version. What I just explained in the question was tested on version 12.2.0 and I tried with almost the same settings in an older version (12.1.2)(on a different machine) and it works as it is expected.

Comment: I have to admit I've had lots of problems with the auctex package in the past. I now run auctex from the git version with no issues. I would recommend you give it a try: "git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/auctex.git".